# Problems using DevPartner

Tags: .net, wpf, devpartner

I'm using DevPartner to track down memory leaks in a long-running .NET/WPF app.  DevPartner tells me what classes are being leaked over time (primarily WeakReference, but also EffectiveValueEntry and WeakDependencySource).

What I need to know is what other object(s) still have references to these in order to prevent them from being garbage-collected.  The DevPartner "View RAM Footprint" report (while the app is running) SHOULD give me this information... but the report will not display.

I'm running the program under "Memory Analysis" mode, and I can see a list of classes with the highest memory consumption or highest instance count.  The "View RAM Footprint" button is enabled, but pressing it appears to have no effect.

I was wondering if anybody else has encountered this issue or if anybody has any suggestions on how to get the report working again.

I tried to look at the MicroFocus forums, but they appear to be down.

Comment: We switched to using AQTime as our primary leak-testing tool because it supports mixed managed/unmanaged leak tracking.  All of the other tools (many of which have better analysis capability) seem to support either managed or unmanaged, but not both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Jeff, what versions of DevPartner and Visual Studio are you using? The new Micro Focus community site just opened. There is not much DevPartner content loaded there yet, but if you post your issue details there you may get someone in customer care to respond. DevPartner Studio 10.5 ships on Feb. 4 so try to obtain that in case your issue is corrected in it. Shameless plug: I am intimately involved in the DevPartner team so I am always looking for ways folks use DevPartner successfully.